# Jib - "Cannot find 'useCurrentTimestamp' "

Tags: jib

I add jib into a pom.xml file as the followings:

```
<properties>
  <docker.org>springcloudstream</docker.org>
  <docker.version>${project.version}</docker.version>
</properties>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <from>
          <image>springcloud/openjdk</image>
        </from>
        <to>
          <image>${docker.org}/${project.artifactId}:${docker.version}</image>
        </to>
        <container>
          <useCurrentTimestamp>true</useCurrentTimestamp>
        </container>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After running the following build command,

```
./mvnw package jib:dockerBuild
```

I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.1.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project usage-detail-sender-kafka: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.1.0:dockerBuild for parameter useCurrentTimestamp: Cannot find 'useCurrentTimestamp' in class com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.JibPluginConfiguration$ContainerParameters
```

The UseCurrentTimestamp is already in the configuration. After an online search, I only find one entry: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/413. I can't see a solution on the page.

What is missing?

Answer (score 8):

The [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-maven-plugin/CHANGELOG.md#changed-1) indicates that `useCurrentTimestamp` was deprecated and removed in 2.0.0:

```
Removed deprecated <container><useCurrentTimestamp> configuration in favor of <container><creationTime> with USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

It looks like you need to replace

```
<useCurrentTimestamp>true</useCurrentTimestamp>
```

with

```
<creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
```

Comment: Also `${maven.build.timestamp}` could be used in favor of `USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`